# Eureka Server does not show configserver micro service - Why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, configserver

I have a created a config server and enabled discovery client on it but my problem is on my eureka server GUI it is not showing under applications tab.

My code is:

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: discovery
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discovery:${server.port}/eureka/

spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: true
```

**Config server as eureka client**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableConfigServer
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8888

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: configserver
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discovery:8761/eureka/

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/kbastani/spring-boot-microservice-config
```

After running the Eureka server first and then config server every thing works fine and there is no exception **but under Instance tab no application is listed please find the screen shot below:**

[image: expecting config server instance here]

Can some one help me understand this ?

Comment: Service discovery clients are registered using ‘spring.application.name’ , do you have that defined?

Comment: Yes in bootstrap.yml I have defines that but not in application.yml

Comment: Does the machine have multiple network interfaces?

Comment: I am not sure about this ? Could you please explain ? I am on learning curve .

Comment: You would first want to run both Discovery client and server on the same host with 'hostname' as 'localhost' and see if it works.